# Problem on a rectangular grid (m×n)

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider a rectangular grid *m×n* consisting of *mn* squares such that we call two squares *neighbours* of each other if they share exactly one side. Then if all the squares are filled each with a number such that the number in each and every square is the *mean* of the numbers in its neighbours, prove that it is necessary for all squares to be filled with the same number.

Now if I start up with a few variables around corner and proceed, I end up taking a lot of variables and stuck. How do I solve this? Just even a hint can help me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Suppose towards a contradiction that the grid is filled with different numbers. Consider a square whose number is highest. (If there is more than one, think about which square to consider.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be the square with the smallest number in it. It's neighbors must either be equal, or have a smaller number (and a larger, to take the mean or average), which contradicts $m$ being the smallest.  Therefore all the squares must contain the same number.